# How to keep recreational players in poker?

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe, online

Poker is experiencing a boom at the moment. Many players are searching for this topic, visiting related sites and poker rules while they have to sit at home. Here is a screenshot of google trends for online poker.

[image]

I want to start a discussion, how to keep that momentum going on. What are the most important factors for you when choosing where to play or if you want to play at all?

- Bigger rakeback
- Promotions targeting fun experience (like chasing some score to open chests like on Pokerstars, etc.)
- Limitation of poker software (mostly only pros use it)
- New poker formats variations

What else is essential for you when deciding where to play?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a lot of players are moving to online simply because they can't play live due to COVID-19. This does not include all of the new players of course, but I would not be surprised if it is a large portion.

For me personally, I look for value in tournaments (guarantee sizes vs. buy in) and the reputation of the site. I also look at the player pool, but this tends to be pretty similar between software. It is also nice to have a customizable experience (changing the buttons for betting/raising, easy player label system with lots of labels, ability to change felt/card color for better visibility).

I hope a lot of the new traffic poker sites are seeing stays around, it is always nice to see new people getting involved in poker.

Comment: Totally agree that many are temporarily moving to online, but not sure if they will be rushing back to casinos the second it opens, I know I won't.

All of the things you mention are super important for playing, but I assume you are a bit more than a recreational player, right? I think players who come simply to have some fun do not care about their bet soldier, or how much there are betting for that matter, so just wondering what is important for them :)

Comment: Things like jackpots and promotions are good for recreational players because it attracts a lot of them. I personally tend to dislike them because they could contribute to problem gambling, a bit like loot box microtransactions in video games if you know anything about that. Players will play stakes they can't afford because they offer jackpots for those stakes, or they will spend more time/money on poker than they would normally be comfortable with because there are jackpots involved. This doesn't apply to the majority of players but its something worth mentioning.

Comment: My answer above is the things that attract me, I think things like unconditional bonuses on deposit (like a 100% bonus on first deposit) are great because it is will draw a lot of new players as well.